# Create RSS feed with PHP Fat Free Framework?

Tags: php, templates, rss, fat-free-framework

I am looking for a way to create an RSS feed from a database query using Fat Free Framework.

Does F3 come with this functionality packaged? Or is there any way to create an RSS feed using an F3 template?

Comment: Yes, this is quite simple with the templating engine. There is a blog demo on github with an rss feed: https://github.com/blo4r/fatfree-blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using the f3 templating engine to output the correct xml, eg:

rss.template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
    <title>{{@blog.title}} </title>
    <link>{{@REALM}}</link>
    <description></description>
    <lastBuildDate>{{date(@blog.date.rss)}}</lastBuildDate>
    <language>{{@LANGUAGE}}</language>
    <atom:link href="{{@REALM}}" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <repeat group="{{@posts}}" key="{{@key}}" value="{{@post}}">
    <item>
        <title>{{@post->title}} </title>
        <pubDate>{{date(@blog.date.rss, @post->date->sec)}}</pubDate>
        <link>http://studio{{@BASE}}/post/{{@post->_id}}/{{tools::slug(@post->title)}}</link>
        <guid>http://studio{{@BASE}}/post/{{@post->_id}}</guid>  
        <description><![CDATA[ {{substr(strip_tags(@post->content),0,256)}} ]]></description>
    </item>
    </repeat>
</channel>
</rss>
```